# Datatables ordering showing older dates before new

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables v1.10 to display my data and for some reason, it is displaying older dates before new dates in the grid. I am using the correct syntax (I think) to order the data but it is not displaying in the correct order. I have tried both `asc` and `desc` and although it is changing the date order, i am confused as to why a newer date is inserted after an older date.

Do I need to add `ORDER BY` to my `sql` or does dt ignore that?

I have done screenshot to show problem and would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

js

```
$(function() {
  $('#nirqst').DataTable({
    "order": [[ 
      9, "desc" 
    ]],
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
      "orderable": false, 
      "targets": [ 10 ]
    },
    {
      className: "hide_id", 
      "targets": [ 0 ]
    }

  ],
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'print',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      },
      title: 'New Intake Report',
      messageTop: 'This report was prepared for ' + usrname + ' on ' + rptDate,
      //text: 'Print current page',
      autoPrint: true,
      customize: function(win) {
        //      $(win.document.body).find('table').css({'background': 'red !important', 'font-size': '24px' });
        $(win.document.body).find('thead').css({
          'background': '#000',
          'font-size': '14px',
          'max-height': '30px'
        });
        $(win.document.body).find('tr:nth-child(odd) td').each(function(index) {
          $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#f7f7f7',
            color: 'black',
            padding: '12px 10px',
            'margin-left': '10px !important'
          });
        });
        $(win.document.body).find('tr:nth-child(even) td').each(function(index) {
          $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#fff',
            color: 'black',
            padding: '12px 10px',
            'margin-left': '10px !important'
          });
        });
        $(win.document.body).find('h1').css({
          'text-align': 'left',
          color: 'black',
          'margin-left': '36px',
          'margin-bottom': '7px',
          'font-size': '28px'
        });
      }
    }, 'copy', 'pdf', 'excel']
  });
  $("#nirqst_wrapper > .dt-buttons").appendTo("#buttons");
//  setInterval(function() {
//table.ajax.reload();
//}, 3000 );
});
```

[image]

Comment: when  you fetch data from database just do order by..

Comment: @SaranyaRajendran I have tried that but hasn't made any difference. If I do the query in phpmyadmin it shows correct ordering. The other interesting thing is that in phpmyadmin I do `ORDER BY `date` ASC` it displays correctly. But in datatables it seems to use `DESC` to show new items first.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull out data from sql the datas that are recorded first will be the first one to be shown so you should put a order by in the date column.

```
select * from [table_name] orderby [date] ASC
```

Comment: Please see my comment above to `Saranya Rajendran `. Thanks